# Loading older checkpoint in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I trained some models using Tensorflow r0.12 and saved it. Later I updated to r1.0.1. Some models are loading without any problems, yet if the model has RNN cells in it, loading fails with `Key layer-5/bidirectional_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_rnn_cell/biases not found in checkpoint`.
Also if I check `model.index` file I see similar entries there, for example: `5/BiRNN/BW/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/BasicRNNCell/Linear/Bias`.

Package with RNN cells is now in `tf.contrib.rnn` (it was `tf.nn.rnn_cell` in 0.12), so I think some naming has been changed.

The question is:
Is there a way to load my model, re-map its tensors and save so that tensor names would be compatible with r1.0?

P.S. I also have `model.meta` file if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If someone gets the same problem, here is the solution I used. It is a modified version of tensor printing function from `inspect_checkpoint.py` in `tensorflow.python.tools`.

```
def resave_tensors(file_name, rename_map, dry_run=False):
    """
    Updates checkpoint by renaming tensors in it.
    :param file_name: Filename with checkpoint.
    :param rename_map: Map from old names to new ones
    :param dry_run: If True, just print new tensors.
    """
    renames_count = 0
    reader = pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader(file_name)
    var_to_shape_map = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
    for key in sorted(var_to_shape_map):
        print("tensor_name: ", key)
        tensor_val = reader.get_tensor(key)
        print('shape: {}'.format(tensor_val.shape))
        if key in rename_map:
            renames_count += 1
            key = rename_map[key]
        tf.Variable(tensor_val, dtype=tensor_val.dtype, name=key)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    if not dry_run:
        with tf.Session() as session:
            session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            saver.save(session, file_name)
    print('Renamed vars: {}'.format(renames_count))
```