# How to make Tensorflow vid2depth inference works?

Tags: tensorflow, inference

I tried to test Tensorflow's vid2depth inference (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/vid2depth).
I followed the instruction of the README. However, I got the below error:

```
ValueError: Couldn't find 'checkpoint' file or checkpoints in given directory vid2depth/trained-model/model-119496
```

I test with tf 0.12, 1.0.0. 1.8 and 1.15.

I used the below command:

```
python3.6 inference.py --kitti_dir ~/vid2depth/kitti-raw-uncompressed --output_dir ~/vid2depth/inference --kitti_video 2011_09_26/2011_09_26_drive_0009_sync --model_ckpt ~/vid2depth/trained-model/model-119496/
```

The content of the checkpoint folder I downloaded is:

```
model-119496.data-00000-of-00001  model-119496.index  model-119496.meta
```

It seems provided files are not in the correct format, but I followed the link of the README.
It seems to be an old checkpoint format ([Loading older checkpoint in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320993/loading-older-checkpoint-in-tensorflow#43324589)).

Could anyone make vid2depth works?

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't download the weights of the model cause the error is saying where are the weights but you provided an empty directory

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I download an archive with 3 files "model-119496.data-00000-of-00001", "model-119496.index" and "model-119496.meta". This not looks like usual checkpoints' folder, but it's the only provided file.

Comment: How about you show the directory or code that will help with the debugging

Comment: I added more details in main post.